# poptGetArgs return null.

Tags: c, linux, getopt, getopts

I am using poptGetArgs to read multiple values for single option. But it always give null as return value. I posted my code below. please help me to resolve if it has any error.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char filename[ 128 ], symbol[32];
    memset(filename, 0x0, 128);
    memset(symbol, 0x0, 32);

    struct poptOption opttable[] =
    {
        { "file", 'f', POPT_ARG_STRING, filename, INPUT_NAME, "filenames to read", "list of files we need to read" },
        { "symbol", 'r', POPT_ARG_STRING, symbol, SYMBOL, "symbol to view", NULL },
        { NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0 }
    };
    poptContext options_socket = poptGetContext( NULL, argc, ( const char **)argv, opttable, 0 );

    int optionvalue(0);
    while( optionvalue > -1 )
    {
        optionvalue = poptGetNextOpt( options_socket );
        if(optionvalue == INPUT_NAME)
        {
           const char ** files = poptGetArgs( options_socket );
           if( files == NULL )
           {
              printf("There was an error while reading input files\n");
           }
        }
        else if( optionvalue == SYMBOL)
        {
           strcpy(symbol, poptGetOptArg( options_socket ));
           printf("symbol you are giving as input is :%s, option value:%d\n", symbol, optionvalue);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An aside: rather than `memset(filename, 0x0, 128);` why not just say `char filename[128] = "";`?

Comment: both are same things.

Answer (score 0):

It is because i am trying to read leftover arguments in the middle (After the file option reading). But all leftover options should be read at the end only. Means i need to read arguments after the while( optionvalue > -1 ) loop. My modified code is

```
enum
{
   INPUT_NAME=1,
   SYMBOL
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char filename[ 128 ], symbol[32];
    memset(filename, 0x0, 128);
    memset(symbol, 0x0, 32);

    struct poptOption opttable[] =
    {
        { "file", 'f', POPT_ARG_STRING, filename, INPUT_NAME, "filenames to read", "list of files we need to read" },
        { "symbol", 'r', POPT_ARG_STRING, symbol, SYMBOL, "symbol to view", NULL },
        { NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0 }
    };
    poptContext options_socket = poptGetContext( NULL, argc, ( const char **)argv, opttable, 0 );

    int optionvalue(0);
    while( optionvalue > -1 )
    {
        optionvalue = poptGetNextOpt( options_socket );
        if(optionvalue == INPUT_NAME)
        {
           strcpy(filename, poptGetOptArg( options_socket));
           printf("file name you are giving as input is :%s, option value:%d\n", filename, optionvalue);
//           const char ** files = poptGetArgs( options_socket );
        }
        else if( optionvalue == SYMBOL)
        {
           strcpy(symbol, poptGetOptArg( options_socket ));
           printf("symbol you are giving as input is :%s, option value:%d\n", symbol, optionvalue);
        }
    }
    const char ** files = poptGetArgs( options_socket );
    if(files == NULL)
    {
        printf("There are no other files left\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's working fine now.